# Json formation in typescript (Angular 7)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

### I have a nested json as below.

```
{
card:[{
    id:1;
    details:[{id:1},{id:2}],
    sheet:{
        id:1
    }
},{
    id:2;
    details:[{id:3},{id:4}],
    sheet:{
        id:1
    }
}
]
}
```

---

### I need to group details based on sheets as below.

```
{
sheet:{
    id:1,
    details:[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
}
 }
```

---

How could I achieve this in typescript?

Went through NPM-groupBy but I don't think it really solves my problem.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: First of all, I don't thin is neither typescript nor angular problem. And looks like its javascript problem. And in your nested json are there any card object with sheet id other than 1?

Comment: Add code where you are creating a nested object.

Comment: i second with @supergentle and you can simply use underscore or other library to solve this, use _.groupBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this would be a good use case for the array reduce method, like:

```
const cards = [
  {
    id: 1,
    details: [
      {id:1},
      {id:2}
    ],
    sheet:{
      id:1
    }
  },
  {
    id:2,
    details: [
      {id:3},
      {id:4}
    ],
    sheet:{
      id:1
    }
  },
  {
    id:3,
    details: [
      {id:5},
      {id:6}
    ],
    sheet:{
      id:2
    }
  }
];

const sheets = cards.reduce( (sheets: Array<any>, card: any) => {
  const existingSheet = sheets.find(sheet => card.sheet.id === sheet.id);
    if (existingSheet) {
      existingSheet.details.concat(card.details);
    } else {
      sheets.push({id: card.sheet.id, details: card.details});
    }
    return sheets;
  }, []
);

console.log(sheets);
```